# Output shown in Jupyter Notebook but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I've seen similar posts but haven't seen any reply that really addresses the difference in outputs between Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm.

An example is like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
now
```

Output:
Jupyter notebook: `datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 8, 13, 20, 37, 339795)`

Pycharm: `Process finished with exit code 0`

There is no output shown in PyCharm. Could someone please explain why there is a difference in the outputs of these two? Any way I can see the same output in PyCharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because Pycharm is running in script mode, while Jupyter is working in interactive mode. You can add print statements such as `print(now)` to see the output, or you can run the code in the Pycharm interactive interpreter.

See this for more details on interactive mode [Python interpretation difference in interactive mode and script mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851026)

See this for more details on how to use the Pycharm interactive interpreter [Does Pycharm have Interactive Python Interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709105)

Comment: Thanks Slim - this is helpful! can  i please ask the pycharm interpreter mode you are referring to is the pycharm console mode which is also an interactive mode?

Comment: @lles yes "Python Console" and the "Show Python Prompt" in debug mode are both interactive.