# How to print an item in PyCharm without print function as Colab?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm testing codes from Colab, where you can just show the result without using print function, such as:

```
df.Quantity.dtypes
```

but in PyCharm, you have to run as the following to show the result:

```
print(df.Quantity.dtypes)
```

It's really time consuming if such commands are frequent.

How could I print out without using print functin in PyCharm just as Colab?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output shown in Jupyter Notebook but not in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231992/output-shown-in-jupyter-notebook-but-not-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a `Jupyter notebook`, but note that **this is a Professional feature**, which means this won't work in PyCharm Community Edition.

Here's how to do it:

1. Create a new Python project, specify a virtual environment, and install the jupyter package.
2. Open or create an .ipynb file.
3. Add and edit source cells.
4. Execute any of the code cells to launch the Jupyter server.

More on PyCharms Jupyter features can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#get-started).

As an alternative, you could you the Python Console. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709105/does-pycharm-have-interactive-python-interpreter) to learn more.